# Wordpress WP_Query posts_per_page not returning correct number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked through other posts on this topic and can not find any reason why my code is behaving like it is. I am looping through my categories list and selecting the single latest post from each category. The issue I am having is even though I am using 'posts_per_page' => 1 the code is returning every post in the category. Here is the code I am using below:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude'=>array(1, 8)));
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="post-cat"><span>Latest</span> <?php echo $cat>name; ?></div>
                <div class="post-image"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></div>
                <div class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                <?php the_excerpt ();?>
                <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Example:

I have a category called How To and I am supposed to be returning the latest post from that category but the code above is displaying the two posts that have that category checked.

EDIT:
Here are the results of the $categories request:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Events [slug] => events [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 3 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 3 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Events [category_nicename] => events [category_parent] => 0 ) [1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 10 [name] => How To [slug] => how-to [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 10 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 2 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 10 [category_count] => 2 [category_description] => [cat_name] => How To [category_nicename] => how-to [category_parent] => 0 ) [2] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 4 [name] => Interviews [slug] => interviews [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 2 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 4 [category_count] => 2 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Interviews [category_nicename] => interviews [category_parent] => 0 ) [4] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 2 [name] => People [slug] => people [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 2 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 2 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => People [category_nicename] => people [category_parent] => 0 ) [6] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 5 [name] => Results [slug] => results [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 5 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 5 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Results [category_nicename] => results [category_parent] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: Try adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to your args array.

Comment: Would you place wp_reset_postdata() just after the endwhile. ?

Comment: Tried the ignore sticky posts but get the same result. Mohammad do you think the wp_reset needs to go inside the foreach loop?

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli tried placing inside the foreach loop got got same result

Comment: @ActionCoding can you show me the result of $category ... how many values does it hold ?

Comment: The original array of $categories contains 5 items but for some reason when it goes into the WP_Query to display the latest post it is displaying multiple posts for each category if a category has multiple posts

Comment: @ActionCoding it is because it gets the posts from each category since you have place the foreach loop. Everytime it looks for particular category posts and displays it and goes on for 5 times since you have said you have 5 categories in $categories

Comment: Yes it is looping through 5 times in the foreach but posts_per_page is one so it should only be selecting 1 post for each loop but that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking at this question. I had to force it to only show the latest by using the code below:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(array('exclude'=>array(1, 8)));
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $args = array(
            'category' => $category->term_id,
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'orderby'=>'date'
        );
        $query = get_posts($args);
        $i = 0;
        foreach($query as $post):setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <?php if($i == 0) { ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="post-cat"><span>Latest</span> <?php echo $category->name; ?></div>
                        <div class="post-image"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></div>
                        <div class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <?php the_excerpt ();?>
                        <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php } $i++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I set it up a little differently and added the $i check so it only used the first occurrence for each loop. This probably isnt the most efficient way to do this so if anyone has suggestions to make the code more efficient I would love that.